# How to create my own markers on Google Maps in my android apps?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api, google-maps-markers

Currently, I'm developing a restaurant finder application. I want to develop a restaurant finder which displays a set of nearby restaurants of current location in Google Map. I already have my own list of restaurants which I created on my own. The list provide the restaurant name, latitude and longitude. Now, I want to add all of these restaurants on the Google Maps by using markers manually.

Does anyone knows any tutorials/examples for my problem? Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: Did you search for it? Have answered this a couple of times already..

Comment: I searched it already. But none of them give me satisfaction. Would you mind to share your search to me?

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html

Answer (score 2):

Look at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker:

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(new LatLng(0, 0))
    .title("Hello world"));
```

Comment: Thank you Catherine for your help. Actually, I'm a newbie in developing android application. You showed a good link there. But I don't know how to start. Is there any good tutorial that can teach me from A-Z about that?

Comment: About adding maps to your app or about app development in general?

Comment: Let's see how can I add maps to my app first.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro